# jackson serialization, is there an annotation that indicates what sub-properties to use for a property?

Tags: java, json, serialization, annotations, jackson

I'd like to see something like this

```
class User {
   @JsonMask({"name", "address"})
   private Company company;
   private String name;
   //...
}
class Company {
   private String name;
   private String address;
   private Set<User> employers;
   //...
}
```

when a user is serialized, the output should be

```
{"name": "Mike", "company": {"name": "Enterprise Co.Ltd", "address": "....." }}
```

and the costly part `Set<User>` and other sub-properties is safely ignored.

I'm not quite familiar with Jackson yet, and found only @JsonIgnore to the rescue, but then I would lose all those @JsonIgnored properties for ever. Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Note: I'm using Hibernate JPA, so in my Model classes there are lots of relations, with deep relation chains and even cyclic references, so a full JSON serialization would always lead to hell ... I googled into @JsonManagedRef and friend, but that only solve the cyclic problem, and leads to a lot of config and is not very readable.

Answer (score 0):

> found only @JsonIgnore to the rescue, but then I would lose all those @JsonIgnored properties for ever

By this I understand that you want the unwanted `Company` properties to be ignored only when serializing a `User`, in contrast to what should happen when otherwise serializing a `Company`, e.g. directly.

If it's possible to use different serializer instances, i.e., two different `ObjectMapper` instances, then one approach to solve this, when serializing a `User`, is to use a [mix-in](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) to apply `@JsonIgnore` as appropriate.  Then don't use that same serializer and mix-in when otherwise serializing a `Company`.

If it's necessary to just have one serializer, then custom serialization is necessary.